# How to capture windows screen at 60 frames per second using api?

Tags: c++, directx, expression-encoder, windows-media-encoder, desktop-duplication

I have tried

1. GDI approach which takes 75 ms to capture 1920x1080 screen.
2. DirectX front buffer approach which takes 84 ms to capture 1920x1080 screen.
3. Desktop Duplication API which is very fast when videos are being played takes 
   9 ms per capture but when the screen is idle/less changes, the capture time increases to 300 ms or more.
4. Tried windows media encoder approach but could not find windows media encoder sdk.

Are there any other ways to do the same with the capability of 60 fps?
I recently got to know that software like Microsoft Expression encoder can capture 60 fps. I'm wondering which api is being used!

Any directions would be appreciated. Thanks in Advance. I am using C++. Does the possible duplicate answer about microsoft expression?

Comment: OBS Studio  is open source: https://github.com/jp9000/obs-studio  Main site: https://obsproject.com/

Comment: @RichardCritten I have gone through the github source, couldn't find the capture module. Can you please help me find the capture module of OBS. Thanks

Comment: @RichardCritten It looks like OBS also uses the Desktop duplication api

Comment: Did you figure it out? I'm also looking for a high performance solution.

Comment: @tunafish24 webrtc getusermedia API is the best I have used so far. You can try it if it fits your requirements